# Unable to JSON Marshal B defined as List[A] using AKKA-Http and Spray-Json

Tags: scala, akka, marshalling, akka-http, spray

as stated in the title, I'm not able to marshal `List[A]` into the proper Json (Array of Objects).

I'm using [AKKA-Http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/) and [Spray-Json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json).

I defined two case classes:

```
final case class Item(id: String, pid: String, title: String)
final case class Items(items: List[Item])
```

And on that call `GET http://localhost:8080/item` received:

```
class ItemEndpoint extends Directives with ItemJsonSupport {

  val route: Route = {
    path("item") {
      get {
        parameters("page".?, "size".?) {
          (page, size) => (page, size) match {
            case (_, _) => 
              onSuccess(Server.requestHandler ? GetItemsRequest){
                case response: Items =>
                  complete(response)
                case _ =>
                  complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }       

}
```

`GetItemsRequest` is called. The latter is defined as

```
case class GetItemsRequest
```

And the `RequestHandler` as

```
class RequestHandler extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var items : Items = _

  def receive: Receive = {
    case GetItemsRequest =>
      items = itemFactory.getItems
      sender() !  items
  }

}
```

Where `getItems` performs a query on `Cassandra` via `Spark`

```
def getItems() : Items = {
    val query = sc.sql("SELECT * FROM mydb")
    Items(query.map(row => Item(row.getAs[String]("item"), 
                           row.getAs[String]("pid"), row.getAs[String]("title")
    )).collect().toList)
}
```

returning `Items` containing `List[Item]`. All the objects are printed correctly (some of them have null fields).

Using `ItemJsonFormatter`

```
trait ItemJsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val itemFormat: RootJsonFormat[Item] = jsonFormat3(Item)
  implicit val itemsFormat: RootJsonFormat[Items] = jsonFormat1(Items)
}
```

Leads to the following error:

> [simple-rest-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(simple-rest-system)] Error during processing of request: 'requirement failed'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed

I tried catching the exception and work on it but I haven't obtained more intel on the problem.

I followed [AKKA DOCS](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/scala/http/common/json-support.html) on marshalling.

When doing the same thing, but getting only 1 item, it works just fine, I obtain a json containing all `Item`'s parameters well formatted.

```
{
    "id": "78289232389",
    "pid": "B007ILCQ8I",
    "title": ""
}
```

Even looking at other related Q/A I was not able to find an answer, so
**What's Causing this? How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the objects are printed correctly (*some of them have null fields*).

The exception could be thrown because `getItems` is returning `Item` objects that have one or more null field values.

One way to handle this is to replace nulls with empty strings:

```
def rowToItem(row: Row): Item = {
  Item(Option(row.getAs[String]("item")).getOrElse(""),
       Option(row.getAs[String]("pid")).getOrElse(""),
       Option(row.getAs[String]("title")).getOrElse(""))
}

def getItems(): Items = {
  val query = sc.sql("SELECT * FROM mydb")
  Items(query.map(row => rowToItem(row)).collect().toList)
}
```

Comment: I cannot test it since I've got some version issues with dependencies. Will accept soon if it works. Anyway, I cannot understand why with a single item this problem does not occur. Even though I have some empty fields, when doing it with a single one I got no errors. Any idea?

Comment: In your example with the single `Item`, the value for the `"title"` field appears to be an empty string, not a null.